# Power builder 2022 and Blueprism Active Accessibility Compatibility Issue

Tags: powerbuilder, blueprism

We have an extensive Blueprism environment that interacts with an in-house CMS system built on power builder 2021. After upgrading to 2022 Blueprism can no longer see a lot of the elements (and can’t spy them either). Visually the application looks the same. I am using active accessibility mode.

Answer (score 0):

This may be related to Powerbuilder 2022 turning off accessibility features by default. Updating the Powerbuilder config to enable accessibility may restore this functionality

This is done in the pb.ini file, presumably setting ACCESSIBILITY=1 rather than ACCESSIBILITY=0 per https://docs.appeon.com/pb2022/troubleshooting_guide/tr_134.html